# Referenced assembly missing strong name after TFS branch

Tags: c#, tfs, visual-studio-2013

I have a project in TFS with references to a strong named dll in a "dependencies" folder. After release, I made a release branch, where a copy of this assembly (that is identical) is located relative at the same place.

However, now Visual Studio 2013 is complaining that this dll don't have a strong name.
When I look at the properties for this reference in VS2013, it surly states that it don't have a strong name. But when comparing the two files, it's reported that it is identical.

Please help....

Best regards,
Thomas